# My Sql Update String Date Time

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried many examples but no one could fix my problem. Below are some examples that I have tried. simply I need to update string date to nullable date time column. what I got is 000-00-00 or NULL column.

thanks for your help I am new at mysql trying to understand :/

```
Update `scorelisting` 
set MaxScoreDate=DATE(STR_TO_DATE('13.05.2012 15:31:00','%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')) 
where UserId=258070

Update `scorelisting` 
set MaxScoreDate=STR_TO_DATE('13.05.2012 15:31:00','%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S') 
where UserId=258070

Update `scorelisting` 
set MaxScoreDate=DATE('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S',STR_TO_DATE('13.05.2012 15:31:00')) 
where UserId=258070

Update `scorelisting` 
set MaxScoreDate=DATE('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S',strtotime('13.05.2012 15:31:00'))
where UserId=258070
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `i` for *Minutes*

```
Update `scorelisting` 
set MaxScoreDate=DATE(STR_TO_DATE('13.05.2012 15:31:00','%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')) 
where UserId=258070
```

Comment: @MertMermi `%M` is for *MonthName*, `%c` is for Month in numeric (0, 12), `%m` Month in numeric also numeric (00..12)

Comment: @MertMermi: `%M` is the month name, in full - see [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: ok thanks I misfound a document which is about php I think :)